# GWT GoogleMaps v3.8 grey area if used inside TabPanel

Tags: gwt, google-maps-api-3

I'm having a problem with gwt GoogleMaps v3.8

This code works just fine as expected:

```
public class TestMaps implements EntryPoint {

    public void onModuleLoad() {
        final SimplePanel sp = new SimplePanel();
        sp.setSize("460px", "320px");
        AjaxLoaderOptions options = AjaxLoaderOptions.newInstance();
        options.setOtherParms("sensor=false&language=en");
        Runnable callback = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                LatLng myLatLng = LatLng.create(51.5171, 0.1062);
                MapOptions myOptions = MapOptions.create();
                myOptions.setZoom(12.0);
                myOptions.setCenter(myLatLng);
                myOptions.setMapTypeId(MapTypeId.ROADMAP);
                GoogleMap.create(sp.getElement(), myOptions);
            }
        };
        AjaxLoader.loadApi("maps", "3", callback, options);
        RootPanel.get("GoogleMapsContainer").add(sp);
    }
}
```

And if I put maps inside TabPanel, I get grey area:

```
public class TestMaps implements EntryPoint {

    private final native static void resizeMap(GoogleMap map) /*-{
        $wnd.google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    }-*/;

    public void onModuleLoad() {
        final DecoratedTabPanel dtp = new DecoratedTabPanel();
        final SimplePanel sp = new SimplePanel();
        sp.setSize("460px", "320px");
        AjaxLoaderOptions options = AjaxLoaderOptions.newInstance();
        options.setOtherParms("sensor=false&language=en");
        Runnable callback = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                LatLng myLatLng = LatLng.create(51.5171, 0.1062);
                MapOptions myOptions = MapOptions.create();
                myOptions.setZoom(12.0);
                myOptions.setCenter(myLatLng);
                myOptions.setMapTypeId(MapTypeId.ROADMAP);
                GoogleMap map = GoogleMap.create(sp.getElement(), myOptions);
                dtp.add(sp, "Tab1", false);
                resizeMap(map);
                map.setZoom(map.getZoom());

            }
        };
        AjaxLoader.loadApi("maps", "3", callback, options);
        RootPanel.get("GoogleMapsContainer").add(dtp);
    }
}
```

I saw few posts around similar problem, but none of the suggestions worked for me.
Any comments, suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: [An image with a grey area maps](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bcfZV.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with GWT, but it looks as if you must trigger the resize-event when you select the tab, not when you add it